# iOS, create JSON object with ABAddressBookCreate's element

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm using **ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions** and **ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople** to achieve all contacts' informations.

I can get person's full name, emails and phone numbers like that:

```
addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++)
{
  ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);


  ////get full name////
  NSString *fullname = @"";
  if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)!=NULL){
      fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
  }
  if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty)!=NULL){
      fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ ", fullname,ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty)];
  }
  if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)!=NULL){
      fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fullname,ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
  }
  fullname = [fullname stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  NSLog(@"fullname: %@",fullname);



  ////get phone numbers////
  ABMultiValueRef phonenumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
  if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phonenumbers)>0)
  {
      for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phonenumbers); j++)
      {
          NSString *phonenumber = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonenumbers, j));
          NSLog(@"phone number: %@",phonenumber);
      }
  }
  CFRelease(phonenumbers);



  ////get emails////
  ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
  if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0)
  {
      for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++)
      {
          NSString *email = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j));
          NSLog(@"email: %@",email);
      }
  }
  CFRelease(emails);
}     

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(people);
```

Everything works perfectly. But I need to create a JSON object with these informations like that:

```
[{"name":"Christine Work","phone_numbers":["+99023424234"]},{"name":"Alex Bla","phone_numbers":["+135352125262","+13433452347"],"email_addresses":["bla@bla.com","bla2@bla2.com"]}]
```

**Scenario**: If person has email address, than add it to json object, if not, not incude it in json.

If person has more than one phone number or more than one email address add all of them to json.

I'm stuck right here. I know how can I create a json object with NSDictionary :

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"alex", @"name",
                                  @"+90225252", @"phones",
                                  nil];

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:info encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but how can I integrate this code to my scenario in the loop.

Comment: What is receiving the JSON? Do you need to include keys even if the object is nil, or can you skip them all together?

Comment: The outermost layer of the JSON is an array, so that's what you should feed into the serializer.  The array contains multiple dictionaries with "name", "phone_numbers", "email_addresses".  The "phone_numbers" and "email_addresses" values are, in turn, arrays.  Should be easy to construct that structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go. Added the necessary code to create the JSON on top of your code. If there are no phone numbers or emails for a contact, NSNull is added for that key. Make sure to check for it when you are pulling the data out of the JSON. Didn't build the code, so let me know if you run into any errors.

```
NSMutableArray *usersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *singleUserDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *phoneNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);

    ////get full name////
    NSString *fullname = @"";
    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)!=NULL){
        fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)];
    }
    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty)!=NULL){
        fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@ ", fullname,ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty)];
    }
    if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)!=NULL){
        fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fullname,ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
    }
    fullname = [fullname stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"fullname: %@",fullname);
    [singleUserDictionary setObject:fullname forKey:@"name"];


    ////get phone numbers////
    ABMultiValueRef phonenumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(phonenumbers)>0)
    {
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phonenumbers); j++)
        {
            NSString *phonenumber = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonenumbers, j));
            NSLog(@"phone number: %@",phonenumber);
            [phoneNumbersArray addObject:phonenumber];
        }
    }
    else
        [phoneNumbersArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
    [singleUserDictionary setObject:phoneNumbersArray forKey:@"phone_numbers"];

    CFRelease(phonenumbers);


    ////get emails////
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    if (ABMultiValueGetCount(emails)>0)
    {
        for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++)
        {
            NSString *email = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j));
            NSLog(@"email: %@",email);
            [emailArray addObject:email];
        }
    }
    else
        [emailArray addObject:[NSNull null]];
    [singleUserDictionary setObject:emailArray forKey:@"email_addresses"];
    CFRelease(emails);

    [usersArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:singleUserDictionary]];
    [singleUserDictionary removeAllObjects];
    [phoneNumbersArray removeAllObjects];
    [emailArray removeAllObjects];
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:usersArray options:0 error:&error];

if (error) {
    //json success
}

CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(people);
```

Comment: I'm stuck on a strange thing for hours. I integrated everything you said, but, when I use : 

    NSLog(@"singleUserDictionary: %@",singleUserDictionary);
    [usersArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:singleUserDictionary]];


console says : 

    singleUserDictionary: {
        "email_addresses" =     (
            "blabla@blabla.com"
        );
        name = "name surname";
        "phone_numbersss" =     (
            "+4643643643"
        );
    }

Comment: it is ok. but when I log the user array at the end :

it gives blank for phone numbers and email addresses

    {
        "email_addresses" =         (
        );
        name = "blabla@blabla.com"";
        "phone_numbersss" =         (
        );
    }

Comment: @woheras Your first comment looks okay to me. Emails and phone numbers are held in an array to account for more than one. Insert a NSLog of the singleUserDictionary before adding one to the usersArray. Then also NSLogs of of the usersArray before and after the singleUserDictionary is added.

Comment: I'm using ARC, when I copy these into the loop:

NSMutableDictionary *singleUserDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *phoneNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *emailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


it works, but why it doesnt work when these are at the top of loop ? I must now release these at the end of loop but I'm using ARC.

Comment: You can't call release with ARC, ARC inserts the releases in for you. It should work outside the loop no problem, I have a similar structure on an app I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo-code:

Create outer NSMutableArray.

For each person --

- create NSMutableDictionary
- insert name
- create NSMutableArray and insert into it phone numbers
- insert the array into dictionary as "phone_numbers"
- repeat for email addresses (if present)
- insert dictionary into array

Run outer array through NSJSONSerialization to serialize into an NSData object